# if function returns string do something | PHP

Tags: php, function, if-statement

This is my function:

```
function getCinemaName($id) {
    $shows = getShowList();

    foreach ($shows as $filmDetails) {

        if ($id == $filmDetails->EventID) {
            if (preg_match('/On/', $filmDetails->AuditoriumShortName)) {
                return 'Cinema One';
                break;
            }
            if (preg_match('/Tw/', $filmDetails->AuditoriumShortName)) {
                return 'Cinema Two';
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want the IF-Statement to do something, if the function returns a specific String.
So is it possible to write something like this:

```
if (getCinemaName('Cinema One')){
    echo"Do something";
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, yes that's possible.

Comment: The argument to `getCinemaName()` is an "id" so if `'Cinema One'` is an id, then you can write something like that.

Comment: ehm, i think it's correct :) what's wrong ?

Comment: it is also possible to run something like this to see if it is possible to write something like this

Comment: sorry, maybe I forgot to write, that I already tested it, but nothing gets displayed... @MuhammedRefaat

Comment: @nicopki well, good to hear your problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
if (getCinemaName($id) === 'Cinema One' ){
    echo "Function returned 'Cinema One' value";
}
```

Also you can read about it some more here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php
and here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (getCinemaName('Cinema One') == 'YourWantedString'){
    echo"Do something";
}
```